# How to get Rails 4 if a record has two conditions return true else false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, helper

I'm setting up my vote system, and trying to have a helper model so I can check if a user has voted for a card. I'm new to rails and can't seem to figure this one out.

How do I have the model check votes for a record that has the `user_id` of the `current_user` and the `card_id`?

I'm also trying to limit calling the helper many times for each iteration of `_cards.html.erb` by setting the `voted` variable. Not sure how to do this, trying to set the variable is just printing true for every card, even the ones that have no votes.

Setting the variable is not working and neither is the helper, as it is always true.

**cards_controller.rb**:

```
def if_voted(card_id)
  if Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :card_id => card_id) then
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
helper_method :if_voted
```

**_cards.html.erb:**

```
<td>
  <%= @voted = if_voted(card.id) %>
  <% if @voted == true %>
    <span class="green"><center>
  <% elsif @voted == false %>
    <span class="red"><center>
  <% else %>
    <span class="gray"><center>
  <% end %>
    <%= card.up_votes - card.down_votes %>
  </center></span>
</td>
```

With the help of @tadman

**cards_controller.rb**

```
def if_voted(card_id)
  if Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :card_id => card_id).any? then
    @vote = Vote.find_by(:user_id => current_user.id, :card_id => card_id)
    return @vote.voted
  else
    return nil
  end
end
helper_method :if_voted
```

**_cards.html.erb**

```
    <td>
      <% @voted = if_voted(card.id) %>
      <% if @voted == true %>
      <span class="green"><center>
      <% elsif @voted == false %>
      <span class="red"><center>
      <% else %>
      <span class="gray"><center>
      <% end %>
        <%= card.up_votes - card.down_votes %>
      </center></span>
    </td>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `where` method always returns a scope even if that scope does not contain any records. The `find_by` method uses the same options but returns either the first matching record or `nil` if none are found.

That's not quite what you want here, though. You don't actually want to retrieve any of the records, but instead just check if they exist. The `any?` method on a scope is `true` if one or more records exist, or `false` otherwise.

You should update your code to look like this:

```
def if_voted(card_id)
  Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :card_id => card_id).any?
end
```

It's worth noting a few things about your Ruby style:

- Using `then` at the end of an `if` clause, while supported, is extraneous and generally not done.
- Comparing things `== true` is usually a sign your logic is confused. If you're concerned about something being literal `true` rather than just logically true, use `=== true` instead. In this case, close enough counts, so `if (if_voted(...))` should suffice.
- Your method returned either `true` or `false` but you had three conditions as if you were expecting a `maybe` to pop up one day.
- Method names like `if_voted` are a little clumsy, especially if used inside an `if`. Something like `has_voted?` is much more in line with Ruby and Rails in general, so you get `if (has_voted?(...))` which reads a lot better.
- Even better would be to migrate this method into the `User` class so you can eliminate the helper and end up with `if (current_user.has_voted?(card_id))` as a very clear way of expressing your intent.